# Is there a way to shorten templated class names when using alias templates in clang?

Tags: c++, clang, c++14, clang++

This is a follow-up to a previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39843027/cant-assign-a-stdunique-ptr-to-a-base-class-in-clang-when-using-an-alias-te/39843150).  Basically, the following program

```
#include <memory>

// Create a class parameterized on a template
template <template <typename> class XX>
struct Foo{};

// Some template with a long name
template <typename T>
struct ReallyLongFileNameThatIHateToType {
};

// Alias to shorten name
template <typename T>
using Bar = ReallyLongFileNameThatIHateToType <T>;

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<Foo<ReallyLongFileNameThatIHateToType>> foo =
        std::make_unique<Foo<Bar>>();
}
```

works just fine with gcc and not clang

```
g++ -std=c++14 test04.cpp -o test04
clang++ -std=c++14 test04.cpp -o test04
test04.cpp:20:61: error: no viable conversion from 'unique_ptr<Foo<template
      Bar>>' to
      'unique_ptr<Foo<template ReallyLongFileNameThatIHateToType>>'
    std::unique_ptr<Foo<ReallyLongFileNameThatIHateToType>> foo =
                                                            ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/include/g++-v4/bits/unique_ptr.h:200:17: note: 
      candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'typename
      _MakeUniq<Foo<Bar> >::__single_object' (aka 'unique_ptr<Foo<Bar> >') to
      'nullptr_t' for 1st argument
      constexpr unique_ptr(nullptr_t) noexcept : unique_ptr() { }
                ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/include/g++-v4/bits/unique_ptr.h:205:7: note: 
      candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'typename
      _MakeUniq<Foo<Bar> >::__single_object' (aka 'unique_ptr<Foo<Bar> >') to
      'std::unique_ptr<Foo<ReallyLongFileNameThatIHateToType>,
      std::default_delete<Foo<ReallyLongFileNameThatIHateToType> > > &&' for 1st
      argument
      unique_ptr(unique_ptr&& __u) noexcept
      ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/include/g++-v4/bits/unique_ptr.h:356:7: note: 
      candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'typename
      _MakeUniq<Foo<Bar> >::__single_object' (aka 'unique_ptr<Foo<Bar> >') to
      'const std::unique_ptr<Foo<ReallyLongFileNameThatIHateToType>,
      std::default_delete<Foo<ReallyLongFileNameThatIHateToType> > > &' for 1st
      argument
      unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = delete;
      ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/include/g++-v4/type_traits:1957:41: note: 
      candidate template ignored: disabled by 'enable_if' [with _Up = Foo<Bar>,
      _Ep = std::default_delete<Foo<Bar> >]
    using _Require = typename enable_if<__and_<_Cond...>::value>::type;
                                        ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/include/g++-v4/bits/unique_ptr.h:228:2: note: 
      candidate template ignored: could not match 'auto_ptr' against
      'unique_ptr'
        unique_ptr(auto_ptr<_Up>&& __u) noexcept;
        ^
1 error generated.
Makefile:2: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

As pointed out in the linked message, this is CWG issue 1244.  Anyway, is there another way to shorten the names that works with clang?  Often, I have code paramterized on template classes, but I don't want to type out the full parameter names over and over again.  When using gcc, I just create the alias template and call it a day.  Evidently, with clang, this doesn't work, so is there a different mechanism to achieve the same affect?

Comment: `using FooBar = Foo<ReallyLongFileNameThatIHateToType>`?

Comment: `auto foo = std::make_unique<Foo<Bar>>();`?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you could make it work other way around by passing template template template parameter to some helper struct to set it with your template template parameter e.g. (working in clang++, c++14):

```
#include <memory>

// Create a class parameterized on a template
template <template <typename> class XX>
struct Foo{};

// Some template with a long name
template <typename T>
struct ReallyLongFileNameThatIHateToType {
};

template <template <template <class> class> class FF>
struct Bar {
  using type = FF<ReallyLongFileNameThatIHateToType>;
};

template <template <template <class> class> class FF>
using Bar_t = typename Bar<FF>::type;


int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<Foo<ReallyLongFileNameThatIHateToType>> foo =
        std::make_unique<Bar_t<Foo>>();
}
```