# Template to template map in C++14

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I want to do a template to template map in C++14. A priori, it seems that the following code does the trick

```
template<class T>
struct KeyType {};

template<class T>
struct ValueType {
    T x;
};

template<template<class> class K>
struct Map;

template<>
struct Map<KeyType> {
    template<class T>
    using type = ValueType<T>;
};

ValueType<int> test{42};
Map<KeyType>::type<int> testM{42}; // Same as above
```

However, the following expression, when compiled with **clang++ v3.8**, returns false.

```
template<template<class> class TemplateType>
struct NeedsTemplate;

std::is_same<
    NeedsTemplate<ValueType>,
    NeedsTemplate<Map<KeyType>::type>
>::value; // False
```

I understand why it is false: [it has already been answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39843027/cant-assign-a-stdunique-ptr-to-a-base-class-in-clang-when-using-an-alias-te/39843150#39843150). Basically, the standard assures that template instantiations of aliases should be recognize as the same, but says nothing about templates them-self. Hence, with **g++**, `std::is_same` is true, and with **clang++**, it is false.

My question is: how can I implement a template to template map that will satisfy the `std::is_same` requirement both with g++ and clang++? I'm willing to use macro as a last resort...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use templates as your metaprogramming primitives.  Use types.  Similar, avoid values.

```
template<template<class...>class Z>
struct ztemplate{
  template<class...Ts>
  using apply=Z<Ts...>;
};
template<class Z, class...Ts>
using apply=typename Z::template apply<Ts...>;
using zapply=ztemplate<apply>;
```

You never work with raw `template`s, just `ztemplate`s.

```
template<class T>
struct KeyType {};
using zKeyType=ztemplate<KeyType>;
```

C++ metaprogramming works much nicer with types.  If you want restrictions on your types (like it must be a `ztemplate`) write SFINAE or psuedo-concepts to enforce it.

As a bonus, a `ztemplate` is a *value* that defines a template.  Which opens you up to hana-style metaprogramming.

This does mean you have to canonically wrap your template code, and strip out direct template and value parameters (replacing with ztemplate and integral constant respectively).  But you end up with much more powerful metaprogramming.

Instead of `X<Blah>` do `apply<zX, Blah>`.  In effect, `apply` becomes the only template you directly use.

Note `apply<zapply, zX, Blah>` and `apply<zapply, zapply, zX, Blah>` etc is the same as `apply<zX, Blah>`.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks. It requires some work, but I think it might be worth it. Something I do not understand: why do you introduce the type `zapply`? Is it only to provide an example?

Comment: @Kevin Well, you you want to be able to metaprogram with `apply` itself, you need it as a type not as a template.  ;)  For example, suppose you have a list of ztemplates and a separate list of types.  First you you generate a cross product of the two lists (generating a list of lists of 2 elements).  Then you fmap apply over the cross product elements or somesuch.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for, in general, is equivalent of functional comparison which is equivalent to the halting problem, i.e., not computable. However...

If you only want to do this for some specific, pre-defined templates, you can specialize them for a tag class and then you can use NeedsTemplate on the tag class. That is,

```
namespace Reflect {
    struct Reflect {};
}

template<class T>
struct KeyType {};

namespace Reflect {
    struct KeyType {};
}

template<>
struct KeyType<Reflect::Reflect> {
    using type = Reflect::KeyType;
};
```

... and then work with `KeyType<Reflect::Reflect>`, which is a type, instead of `KeyType`, which is a template. Note that you might still take `KeyType` (template) on the interface; you just call `std::is_same<>` on reflections. Also note, this requires you to write the reflection for each type - albeit that's trivial with macros. Also, you can't use `Reflect::Reflect` as a key type. (You could do this the other way, via traits, but then you're specializing in the traits' namespace, which is a bit tricky with multiple files.)

```
#define REFLECT_TEMPLATE(TEMPL) \
    namespace Reflect {                \
        struct TEMPL {};               \
    };                                 \
    template<>                         \
    struct TEMPL<Reflect::Reflect> {   \
        using type = Reflect::KeyType; \
    };
```

If I were you, I'd also add a `const char* name() const` to the reflected type...

Comment: Very interesting the parallel to the halting problem, thanks!